# Unrender component created by ReactDOM.render when the container is unrendered

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend

There're two component developed in two different application.
One is App. Another one is MFE1.
In real world we have MFE2, MFE3, MFE4...etc. And App is just a container.
We will load different MFE into App using ReactDOM.render(Match by id).

The whole thing is actually working fine but there's only one existing issue.
We cannot find a way to unrender MFE1 when its container is unrendered.
I tried to call unmountComponentAtNode inside the useEffect callback of the App container.
However since the DOM is already gone at this point so we cannot use this method.

At its simplest level, my question is how can I unrender the MFE1 when/after I unrender its container?

I have created a sandbox to simulate the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-black-7swzbt

Inside the sandbox, I already implemented the way we load these MFE1 into App.

There's two buttons inside the sandbox.

Button switch mfe simulate the way we switch between different MFEs.
When you click it, you will see the MFE1 is invisible in the page, however it is not unrendered yet since the console.log("MFE1 is unrendered") is not called.

Button unmountComponentAtNode simulate the expected behavior, you can see MFE1 is invisible in the page, also the console.log("MFE1 is unrendered") is called. However I cannot use it inside the useEffect callback...

Comment: Upgrade to React 18 at the end since it is too annoying to handle this in React 17. We do it by eventListener. Since React 18, we can access createdRoot even if the div has been removed. We can then add eventListener for root.unmount when Micro-frontend is loaded. When we switch to different Micro-frontend, we dispatch the event to unmount them.